# High voltage circuit powering Arduino/ESP32 - requesting feedback?

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, schematics, electrical, esp32

I have been struggling with this for days...This is the first time using switched power supply units to power an Arduino.

Can you tell me if this is wired correctly? If not, what needs to be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The green status light should be connected between the Line and Neutral terminal blocks, and the top terminal of the Master On switch should go directly to the Line terminal block.

As you have it wired, all the AC input current will flow through the status light, so most of the input voltage will be dropped across the light, leaving very little for the two power supplies.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and explanation. I have updated the schematic accordingly. Cheers

Comment: Anything else appear incorrect?